# How do you stick a QDialog into a custom delegate?

Tags: qt

When you create your own custom delegate, you implement `createEditor()`, `setEditorData()` and `setModelData()`. I am facing the following problem. All the examples of `createEditor()` that I have seen use simple things like QComboBox or QLineEdit, which don't have `show()` or `exec()` member functions, and whenever I try to use QDialog, the program has undefined behavior (I think) and the QDialog shows up but acts crazy. I did get my program to work, using some signal/slot magic, but I'd like to implement it using the standard pattern described, for example, here: http://cep.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2/model-view-delegate.html how can I do it?

To elaborate on what happens when I face that undefined behavior, if I set QDialog's parent in createEditor(), then QDialog doesn't show at all, if I don't set it, it shows up and then when I drag it around it disappears (this is wrong anyway and I think I have to always set the parent because otherwise I'll have a memory leak). I guess, now my question boils down to: how can I make QDialog show properly? I tried sticking show() and exec() into different parts of setEditorData(), setModelData() and createEditor() but nothing works properly.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a dialog and not a widget?

Comment: @Hayt, I just want a separate window, because I want to display a QTreeView there.

Comment: create a custom widget not a dialog. You can stick the widget in your delegate.

Comment: @Hayt, but I want a seperate window, in my custom delegate I tried sticking a QTreeWidget and it doesn't work, the index that I click on doesn't get expanded.

Comment: @Hayt, now it works fine if I do setFocus on some widget that's in my QDialog. Why does this happen? Do you know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An editor delegate must be a widget that's embedded in the view. It is free to create a top-level window if it wishes so, of course, but it must control that window's visibility and focus appropriately. Namely, if the editor widget's visibility changes, so must the dialog's, and if the editor widget gains focus, you must transfer the focus to the dialog for good UX.

The solution is to have an empty `QWidget` that has a child `QDialog` that is a top-level window:

```
QWidget * MyDelegate::createEditor(QWidget * parent, 
                  const QStyleOptionViewItem &, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
  auto editor = new QWidget{parent};
  auto dialog = new QDialog{editor, Qt::Window};
  ...
  return editor;
}
```

The reason that your `QDialog`-editor didn't work is that its geometry and state were managed by the view. The view acts like a layout for the editors/delegates.  You need to insert an intervening widget to shield your dialog from such manipulation. Admittedly, the views could check the editor's flags and refrain from adjusting geometry etc. if it had the `Qt::Window` flag set, but it's so rare that I don't blame anyone for not implementing it. You're free to submit a change to Qt, of course!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do I make the QDialog open up when I double click on the QModelIndex of my main window?

Comment: Oh, you probably meant that I need to create a custom QWidget that   has a dialog as its member and calls exec on it, in its constructor?

Comment: @Pavel You're right about the custom widget. Also, use `show()`, not `exec()`. Generally speaking, `QDialog::exec()` is a bad idea, since it makes your code look pseudo synchronous, whereas the real world isn't.

Comment: ok, but then I face another problem: I don't know when setModelData in my delegate is called, when my dialog, that is stored within that widget, is closed, this doesn't happen, how do I handle that and make it so that when I close my dialog, setModelData gets called? Through signals and slots again or is there a better way?

Comment: @Pavel 1. Implement your dialog so that when the user accepts the changes, the `accept()` method is called. 2. Connect the dialog's `accepted()` signal to a functor that sets the data.

Answer (score 2):

The delegate`s methods are for inline editors, widgets that get displayed inside the view.

If you want to have an extern editor you might want to just react to the view's signals, e.g. `clicked()` and open your dialog from that slot.

Comment: Where does it say that it's for inline editors? Can I have a reference?

Comment: That's part of the delegate concept in Qt's model/view architecture. The delegate "is used to display and edit data items from a model."
The delegate is used by the view to handle single cells, referred to by the respective `QModelIndex`.
The editor is the widget that gets displayed instead of the cell's usual visualization, in order to facilitate input rather than display

Comment: thanks, well, I did manage to get it to work with signals and slots, I just wanted to see how to make it work like all the other editors.

Answer (score 2):

The [proposal above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40275439/2056686) by K. Ober to implement QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor() to use an empty QWidget instance as editor and give it the dialog as child is a working solution.

However, according to Qt tech support the QStyledItemDelegate not only supports embedding of QWidget in a table cell for inline editing but editing in a separate window outside the table via a QDialog as the editor as well.
That means you may directly return a QDialog derived class as the editor in createEditor(), as demonstrated by the following working example.

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class MyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
  using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
  public:
  QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem&, const QModelIndex&) const {
    auto *fd = new QFileDialog(parent);
    fd->open();
    return fd;
}

void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    auto fd = qobject_cast<QFileDialog *>(editor);
    if (!fd || fd->result() == QDialog::Rejected)
        return;
    model->setData(index, fd->selectedFiles().first(), Qt::DisplayRole);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QStandardItemModel sim(5, 5);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        sim.setItem(i, j, new QStandardItem("Item"));

  QTableView tv;
  tv.setModel(&sim);
  tv.setItemDelegate(new MyDelegate(&tv));
  tv.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: The problem I have with this answer is that if I click outside my custom `QDialog` then it closes similar to how a delegate widget auto-closes when losing focus. Setting the dialog to Modal almost works, but clicking outside of the app still forcibly closes my `QDialog`.